# Conversion of Reich-Moore resonance parameters to neutron cross section?

Tags: nuclear-physics, resonance, neutrons, scattering-cross-section, nuclear-engineering

For the Single-Level Breit-Wigner (SLBW) formula, the peak resonant neutron cross section is related to the total width, $\Gamma = \Gamma_{(n)} + \Sigma_{r}\Gamma_{(r)}$, reported as GT in ENDF. For Reich-Moore (RM) resonance parameters format, however, there is no reported total resonance width (see for example:
[U-238(N,RES) interpreted resonance parameters](https://www-nds.iaea.org/exfor/servlet/E4sGetIntSection?SectID=19166995&req=8&e4up=0&PenSectID=24014540&pen=0).) For Reich-Moore format, then, is $\Gamma$ still equal to the sum of the partial widths (GG, GN, GFA, GFB), and if not, how does one calculate the peak neutron cross section from the given partial widths?

Answer (score 0):

The "Reich-Moore formalism" in ENDF-6 is actually not the "true" Reich-Moore formalism, some approximations were made in order to fit the restrictions of the format and to include 2 partial fission channels. Using this approximation you have indeed the Gtot=GN+GG+GFA+GFB.

You can find, or rather deduce, informations on this approximated-formalism in the ENDF-6 manual's appendix, but I acknowldge it should be written explicitely in the corresponding section.